# Create list of Response object names rather than list of strings

Tags: python, for-loop, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I am collecting Census data using the Requests library. In order to process each returned Request, I use `%who_ls Response` to show all Response objects in memory. However, this returns a list of strings and I need a list of Response object names to then send through a loop. This code works, but I want to improve it by automatically generating the list of Response objects (*see* `concat_response_objects` *below*).

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

age_by_zip = requests.get("https://api.census.gov/data/2018/acs/acs5/subject?get=S0101_C01_001E,S0101_C01_028E,S0101_C01_022E,S0101_C01_032E&for=zip%20code%20tabulation%20area:*")
age_by_city = requests.get("https://api.census.gov/data/2018/acs/acs5/subject?get=S0101_C01_001E,S0101_C01_028E,S0101_C01_022E,S0101_C01_032E&for=place:*")
race_by_county = requests.get("https://api.census.gov/data/2017/acs/acs5?get=B03001_003E,B02001_001E,B02001_002E,B02001_006E,B02001_005E,B02001_004E,B02001_003E&for=place:*")
race_by_zip = requests.get("https://api.census.gov/data/2017/acs/acs5?get=B03001_003E,B02001_001E,B02001_002E,B02001_006E,B02001_005E,B02001_004E,B02001_003E&for=zip%20code%20tabulation%20area:*")
sex_by_zip = requests.get("https://api.census.gov/data/2018/acs/acs5/subject?get=S0101_C01_033E&for=zip%20code%20tabulation%20area:*")
sex_by_city = requests.get("https://api.census.gov/data/2018/acs/acs5/subject?get=S0101_C01_033E&for=place:*")

# Need to automate generating the list of Response Objects. %who returns string name, but not actual object name. 
w = %who_ls Response
print(w)

# Currently I hand-enter all Response object names. I would like to create this list automatically, using %who_ls Response or a different solution.
concat_response_objects = [age_by_zip, age_by_city, race_by_zip, race_by_city, sex_by_zip, sex_by_city]

# Loop through response objects, format and send to CSV
columns = w

for idx, data in enumerate(concat_response_objects):
    data = data.json()
    data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    data.columns = data.iloc[0]
    with open(columns[idx] + '.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        data.to_csv(outfile, index=False)
```

I've tried using `.replace("'", "")` but the data was still strings.

```
test = []
for n in w: 
    test.append(n.replace("'", ""))
```

Comment: `replace()` doesn't convert strings to objects

Comment: Yes, I know. I tried it and it didn't work.I don't need it to covert to objects per se, I just need to drop the ticks around the string so that I can use it to find objects in memory.